# Issue with xkeyval package and special characters while compiling with LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, packages, package-writing, lua, xkeyval

The following is the code of document `myfile.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|ccc|c|c|}
\myPrint[trtext=Yes, fltext=No]{p,q,r}{stu} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The following is the code of `test.sty` file.

```
\ProvidesPackage{luatruthtables}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function test(x,y,trtext,fltext)
  trtext= trtext or "Tr"
  fltext = fltext or "Fl"
  return x .. "  " ..  y .. "  " ..  trtext .. "  " .. fltext
end
\end{luacode*}

% ========= KEY DEFINITIONS =========
\define@key{someop}{trtext}{\def\mop@type{#1}}
\define@key{someop}{fltext}{\def\mop@truncate{#1}}

% ========= KEY DEFAULTS =========
\setkeys{someop}{trtext=Tr,fltext=Fl}%
% ========= Defining Command =========
\newcommand{\myPrint}[3][]{%
  \begingroup%
  \setkeys{someop}{#1}
  \directlua{tex.sprint(test(\luastringN{#2},\luastringN{#3},"\mop@type","\mop@truncate"))}
  %
  \endgroup%
}


\endinput
```

It works fine. However, when I change the line `return x .. "  " ..  y .. "  " ..  trtext .. "  " .. fltext` by the line `return x .. " &  " ..  y .. "  " ..  trtext .. "  " .. fltext`,it throws the error that `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`. Note that I am simply adding `&`  to the code. Does it cause the error?

Comment: a tabular cell is a group, if you set some keys in one cell then "simply add &" the group will end and all key settings will be lost, and typically you will get some weird internal parsing error as the group ended at a bad place  here even without th Lua, just try `\begingroup a & b \endgroup` in a tabular: that can not work

Comment: So what is the way out ? How can the issue be resolved?

Comment: as I was just writing in an answer, it depends what you want to do, you can remove the group, but it depends what effect you intended the group to have.

Comment: Thanks. That resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \begingroup x & y \endgroup
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which gives the error

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate 
l.6   \begingroup x &
                      y \endgroup
?
```

As a table cell is a group and you can not end the group started with `\begingroup` by `&`, nor end the group started by `&` with `\endgroup`.

In this case simply removing the `\begingroup\endgroup` fixes he issue, but it depends why you have the group in your real code.

As well as the `\begingroup` you will have the issue that all the key settings are lost at the `&` so only available in the first cell of the row.

Comment: Is it possible to use `\luastringN{\mop@type}` instead of  `"\mop@type"` in my code. I found that it is not working. So how `\luastringN` can be used in `xkeyval` package?

Comment: @user61681 I never find the luacode packages commands particularly useful, I'd just use the luatex primitives directly,  but what do you want `\luastringN{\mop@type}` to do? `\luastringN` is for no expansion, but you want to expand `\mop@type` (I would guess) so I assume you want `\luastring`

Comment: `\myPrint[trtext=\(Yes\), fltext=No]{p,q,r}{stu}` doesn't work but the command` `\myPrint[trtext=\\(Yes\\), fltext=No]{p,q,r}{stu}`  works in my code of the question. So how to escape backslash in my code ?